# Using callbacks with simple action clients

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I am trying to use a goal callback and a feedback callback with my move base action client. I am getting a really long and hard to understand error though. I was hoping someone might be able to help me decipher it.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
void GoToBehavior::goalCallback(const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState& state,
                    const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult::ConstPtr& result) {
    if(state == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED)
        ROS_INFO("Goal reached!");
    else
        ROS_INFO("Goal failed");
}

void GoToBehavior::feebackCallback(const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback::ConstPtr& feedback){

}

void GoToBehavior::execute(){
    ROS_INFO("Sending goal");
    ac->sendGoal(goalMsg,
                boost::bind(&GoToBehavior::goalCallback, this, _1, _2),
                MoveBaseClient::SimpleActiveCallback(),
                boost::bind(&GoToBehavior::feebackCallback, this, _1));
}
```

where ac is of type: actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction>

The error I am getting is this:

> In file included from
> /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
> from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
> from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
> from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/ros.h:45,
> from /home/nick/mqp_ws/src/mqp/hulk/include/hulk/Behavior.h:5,
> from /home/nick/mqp_ws/src/mqp/hulk/include/hulk/GoToBehavior.h:5,
> from /home/nick/mqp_ws/src/mqp/hulk/src/GoToBehavior.cpp:1:
> /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In
> member function ‘void
> boost::_bi::list3<A1, A2,
> A3>::operator()(boost::_bi::type,
> F&, A&, int) [with F =
> boost::*mfi::mf2<void, GoToBehavior,
> const
> actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&,
> const boost::shared_ptr<const
> move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
>
> > > &>, A = boost::*bi::list2<const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, A1 = boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*>, A2 =
> > > boost::arg<1>, A3 = boost::arg<2>]’:
> > > /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:102:59:
> > > instantiated from
> > > ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F,
> > > L>::result_type boost::*bi::bind_t<R,
> > > F, L>::operator()(const A1&, const
> > > A2&) [with A1 =
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState, A2 =
> > > boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseResult*std::allocator<void
> > > , R = void, F = boost::*mfi::mf2<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, L = boost::_bi::list3boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >,
> > > boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F,
> > > L>::result_type = void]’
> > > /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153:11:
> > > instantiated from ‘static void
> > > boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker2<FunctionObj,
> > > R, T0,
> > > T1>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&,
> > > T0, T1) [with FunctionObj =
> > > boost::_bi::bind_t<void,
> > > boost::*mfi::mf2<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, boost::*bi::list3boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, R =
> > > void, T0 = const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, T1
> > > = const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &]’ /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:913:60:
> > > instantiated from ‘void
> > > boost::function2<R, T1,
> > > T2>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor
> > > = boost::*bi::bind_t<void, boost::*mfi::mf2<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, boost::*bi::list3boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, R =
> > > void, T0 = const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, T1
> > > = const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &]’ /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:
> > > instantiated from ‘boost::function2<R,
> > > T1, T2>::function2(Functor, typename
> > > boost::enable_if_cboost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor::value>::value,
> > > int>::type) [with Functor =
> > > boost::*bi::bind_t<void,
> > > boost::*mfi::mf2<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, boost::*bi::list3boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, R =
> > > void, T0 = const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, T1
> > > = const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &, typename boost::enable_if_cboost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor::value>::value,
> > > int>::type = int]’
> > > /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:16:
> > > instantiated from
> > > ‘boost::function<R(T0,
> > > T1)>::function(Functor, typename
> > > boost::enable_if_cboost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor::value>::value,
> > > int>::type) [with Functor =
> > > boost::*bi::bind_t<void,
> > > boost::*mfi::mf2<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, boost::*bi::list3boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, R =
> > > void, T0 = const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, T1
> > > = const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &, typename boost::enable_if_cboost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor::value>::value,
> > > int>::type = int]’
> > > /home/nick/mqp_ws/src/mqp/hulk/src/GoToBehavior.cpp:37:70:
> > > instantiated from here
> > > /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:392:9:
> > > error: no match for call to
> > > ‘(boost::*mfi::mf2<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &>) (GoToBehavior*&, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &)’ /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:253:75:
> > > note: candidates are:
> > > /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:278:7:
> > > note: R boost::*mfi::mf2<R, T, A1,
> > > A2>::operator()(T*, A1, A2) const
> > > [with R = void, T = GoToBehavior, A1 =
> > > const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, A2
> > > = const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &] /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:278:7:
> > > note:   no known conversion for
> > > argument 3 from ‘const
> > > boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseResult*std::allocator<void
> > > ’ to ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &’ /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:283:25:
> > > note: template R
> > > boost::*mfi::mf2::operator()(U&, A1,
> > > A2) const [with U = U, R = void, T =
> > > GoToBehavior, A1 = const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, A2
> > > = const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &] /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:291:25:
> > > note: template R
> > > boost::*mfi::mf2::operator()(const U&,
> > > A1, A2) const [with U = U, R = void, T
> > > = GoToBehavior, A1 = const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, A2
> > > = const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &] /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:299:7:
> > > note: R boost::*mfi::mf2<R, T, A1,
> > > A2>::operator()(T&, A1, A2) const
> > > [with R = void, T = GoToBehavior, A1 =
> > > const
> > > actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, A2
> > > = const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionResult*std::allocator<void
> > > &] /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:299:7:
> > > note:   no known conversion for
> > > argument 1 from ‘GoToBehavior*’ to
> > > ‘GoToBehavior&’
> > > /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In
> > > member function ‘void
> > > boost::_bi::list2<A1,
> > > A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type,
> > > F&, A&, int) [with F =
> > > boost::*mfi::mf1<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, A = boost::*bi::list1<const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, A1 = boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*>, A2 =
> > > boost::arg<1>]’:
> > > /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:47:59:
> > > instantiated from
> > > ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F,
> > > L>::result_type boost::*bi::bind_t<R,
> > > F, L>::operator()(const A1&) [with A1
> > > = boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > , R = void, F = boost::*mfi::mf1<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, L = boost::_bi::list2boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1> >, boost::_bi::bind_t<R,
> > > F, L>::result_type = void]’
> > > /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153:11:
> > > instantiated from ‘static void
> > > boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<FunctionObj,
> > > R,
> > > T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&,
> > > T0) [with FunctionObj =
> > > boost::_bi::bind_t<void,
> > > boost::*mfi::mf1<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, boost::*bi::list2boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1> > >, R = void, T0 =
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &]’ /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:913:60:
> > > instantiated from ‘void
> > > boost::function1<R,
> > > T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor
> > > = boost::*bi::bind_t<void, boost::*mfi::mf1<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, boost::*bi::list2boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1> > >, R = void, T0 =
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &]’ /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:
> > > instantiated from ‘boost::function1<R,
> > > T1>::function1(Functor, typename
> > > boost::enable_if_cboost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor::value>::value,
> > > int>::type) [with Functor =
> > > boost::*bi::bind_t<void,
> > > boost::*mfi::mf1<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, boost::*bi::list2boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1> > >, R = void, T0 =
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &, typename boost::enable_if_cboost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor::value>::value,
> > > int>::type = int]’
> > > /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:16:
> > > instantiated from
> > > ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor,
> > > typename
> > > boost::enable_if_cboost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor::value>::value,
> > > int>::type) [with Functor =
> > > boost::*bi::bind_t<void,
> > > boost::*mfi::mf1<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &>, boost::*bi::list2boost::_bi::value<GoToBehavior*,
> > > boost::arg<1> > >, R = void, T0 =
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &, typename boost::enable_if_cboost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor::value>::value,
> > > int>::type = int]’
> > > /home/nick/mqp_ws/src/mqp/hulk/src/GoToBehavior.cpp:37:70:
> > > instantiated from here
> > > /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:9:
> > > error: no match for call to
> > > ‘(boost::*mfi::mf1<void, GoToBehavior,
> > > const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &>) (GoToBehavior*&, const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &)’ /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:136:65:
> > > note: candidates are:
> > > /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:163:7:
> > > note: R boost::*mfi::mf1<R, T,
> > > A1>::operator()(T*, A1) const [with R
> > > = void, T = GoToBehavior, A1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &] /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:163:7:
> > > note:   no known conversion for
> > > argument 2 from ‘const
> > > boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > ’ to ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &’ /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:168:25:
> > > note: template R
> > > boost::*mfi::mf1::operator()(U&, A1)
> > > const [with U = U, R = void, T =
> > > GoToBehavior, A1 = const
> > > boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &] /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:176:25:
> > > note: template R
> > > boost::*mfi::mf1::operator()(const U&,
> > > A1) const [with U = U, R = void, T =
> > > GoToBehavior, A1 = const
> > > boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &] /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:184:7:
> > > note: R boost::*mfi::mf1<R, T,
> > > A1>::operator()(T&, A1) const [with R
> > > = void, T = GoToBehavior, A1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const
> > > move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionFeedback*std::allocator<void
> > > &] /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:184:7:
> > > note:   no known conversion for
> > > argument 1 from ‘GoToBehavior*’ to
> > > ‘GoToBehavior&’

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202310/using-callbacks-with-simple-action-clients/) by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-02-03**:
Please format the error message properly. It will make it much more easier to read.

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2015-02-03**:
I'm sorry for not formatting it correctly, I thought I just needed to put it in the quote box. What should I have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try removing the 'Action' from your types. That is, for instance, change `MoveBaseActionResult` to `MoveBaseResult`.

I'm not sure that's actually the issue, but it's what jumps out at me...

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2015-02-03**:
That was it, thank you for your help!